# Python - TKinter. Is there way to detect if Scale (slider) value was changed while specific key was pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, keypress

I have Scale widget to set int-value for color of circle to draw. In default way we just set value for the color variable:

```
def get_color(value):
    figures_color.set(value)

scale_color = tk.Scale(root, label='Color', variable = figures_color, from_=1200, to=24000, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=500, showvalue=0, tickinterval=2000, command=get_color)
```

But I'm interested in other option. If scale value was changed while `Shift` key was pressed, we need to mark that circle should be also filled with some color. Something like this:

```
def get_color_fill(event):
    fill_circle = True
```

But I have no idea how to make it in proper way (or if it is even possible). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .bind() method in Tkinter to run a function on a key press. Example code:

```
def get_color_fill(event):
    fill_circle = True

def get_color(value):
    figures_color.set(value)

scale_color = tk.Scale(root, label='Color', variable = figures_color, from_=1200, to=24000, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=500, showvalue=0, tickinterval=2000, command=get_color)

scale_color.bind('<Shift-KeyPress>', get_color_fill) #Using the .bind() method
```

Another way to check if a key was pressed is to use the keyboard module. You need to first install it using:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Then in your code:

```
import keyboard

def get_color_fill(event):
    fill_circle = True

def get_color(value):
    if not keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        figures_color.set(value)

    elif keyboard.is_pressed('shift'):
        get_color_fill()

scale_color = tk.Scale(root, label='Color', variable = figures_color, from_=1200, to=24000, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=500, showvalue=0, tickinterval=2000, command=get_color)
```

The second method is better, since you want to run the get_color_fill() function if the shift key is pressed while changing the value of the scale.

Comment: This isn't necessary, at all. Tkinter already has keyboard/mouse/other events bindings built-in. The real answer (generally speaking) is: `scale_color.bind('<KeyPress-Shift>', get_color_fill)`

Comment: It is not guarantied that the scale widget get the keyboard focus when changing its value using mouse drag.  So the tkinter event binding may not work.

Comment: @acw1668 - That's why I said "generally speaking". There isn't enough code to determine which widget should be the listener.

Comment: @OysterShucker *"General speaking it may not work"* is more correct.

Comment: @acw1668 - The point was to illustrate the built-in syntax.

Comment: Binding <KeyPress-Shift> seems pretty simple but I'm getting an error: `_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Shift"`

Also @acw1668 is right about focusing the widget

Comment: The event is `<Shift-KeyPress>`.  Also OP want to update the flag when the scale is changing, not every press of the Shift key.

Comment: @st_dec - I'm sorry, I wrote it backwards. I forgot that shift is considered a modifier instead of a detail. (`<modifier-type-detail>`)